# Python zeep overview of the services available

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, zeep

I have been working with python zeep to inspect the WSDL document and generates the corresponding code to use the services and types in the wsdl document.

The code below is a short example. It partially works. The problem is: These parameters is not exactly what the web service is waiting for

```
client = Client(wsdl='veda/wsdl/vedascore-apply-v2-0-6.wsdl')
client.service.submitEnquiry('Zeep', 'is cool')
```

In order to find out what I was supposed to send and to get an overview of the services available on the endpoint, I performed the following command in my terminal:

```
python -mzeep 'veda/wsdl/vedascore-apply-v2-0-6.wsdl'
```

The result of the command above is a big text file which I will attached [here](http://textuploader.com/d1zka). Now that I have an overview of the services I guess I was supposed to create a proper call signature. I also went through the official documentation and I manage to perform the follow code:

```
    client = Client(wsdl='veda/wsdl/vedascore-apply-v2-0-6.wsdl')
    request_type = client.get_type('ns0:requestType')
    client.service.submitEnquiry(request_type)
```

The code above is not even close to the final solution. In order to build a proper call I have to understand the overview of the services available which I am struggling to do. The image below is just part of the description. If you can please give me any ideas I am more than happy to listen to you.

[overview of the services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTwwL.png)

Warm Regards.

Ronildo Braga Junior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if you are facing the same problem, please see below how you was supposed to craft this call

```
    enquiry_header = {
        'client-reference': 'my-ref-101',
        'operator-id': 101,
        'operator-name': 'Adam Hills',
        'permission-type-code': 'XY',
        'product-data-level-code': 'N',
        'requested-scores': {'scorecard-id': ['VSA_2.0_XY_NR']}
    }

    enquiry_data = {
        'individual': {
            'current-name': {
                'title': 'Mr',
                'family-name': 'Hunt',
                'first-given-name': 'Matthew',
                'other-given-name': 'Eales'
            },
            'addresses': {
                'address': [{
                    'type': 'C',
                    'unit-number': 12,
                    'street-number': 4,
                    'street-name': 'Huntsman',
                    'street-type': 'CIR',
                    'suburb': 'Pyrmont',
                    'state': tf.stateType('NSW'),
                    'postcode': 2011
                }]
            },
            'drivers-license': {'number': '758811G'},
            'gender-code': 'M',
            'date-of-birth': '1970-01-26',
            'employment': {
                'employer': [employerType(name='DATA FISH PTD LTD', type='C')]
            }
        },
        'enquiry': {
            'account-type-code': 'PR',
            'enquiry-amount': tf.MoneyType(5000, 'AUD'),
            'is-credit-review': False,
            'relationship-code': 1
        }
    }

    print(client.service.submitEnquiry(enquiry_header, enquiry_data))
```